# How do I use an updated value in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, use-effect

I'm new to Javascript and I'm currently experimenting with the Demo application out of the Docker [getting-started tutorial](https://github.com/docker/getting-started). The application is a simple Todo list where you can add items and remove them.

I'm trying to update the list on every instance of the page without having to reload the page.
I've managed to edit the node express server so that it sends updates via Server-sent events.

The problem:
The frontend uses React. The data of the currently displayer items is contained in the `ìtems` array.
`onNewItem` adds items to that array. However when `onNewItem` is called from `onmessage` the items array is null even though it's not null when `onNewItem` is called from other React components. How can I access the initialized version of the `items` array? (It gets initialized by the 1. useEffect which fetches items from the server)

Below is a part of the code

```
function TodoListCard() {
const [items, setItems] = React.useState(null);

const [ listening, setListening ] = React.useState(false);

React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/items')
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(setItems);
}, []);

React.useEffect( () => {
    if (!listening) {
    const events = new EventSource('/events/subscribe');
    events.onmessage = (event) => {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        switch (parsedData.type) {
            case "add":
                var newItem = {id: parsedData.id, name: parsedData.name, completed: parsedData.completed};
                onNewItem(newItem);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };

    setListening(true);
    }
}, [listening]);

const onNewItem = React.useCallback(
    newItem => {
        if (items.some(e => e.id === newItem.id)){return;}
        setItems([...items, newItem]);
    },
    [items],
);
```

Comment: @Lcj why do you initialize `items` as `null` instead of `[]`?

Comment: It's part of the original tutorial code.

Comment: I just tried to do ```setItems([]);``` before the useEffects but it threw an error

Comment: Can you provide a link to the tutorial or at least show how items is used in the `TodoListCard`? Feel free to [edit] the information into your question.

Comment: I changed the ```false``` in React.useState to [] but the array used by the two useEffects is still not the same

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to change `listening` initial value... The tutorial code you started with is poorly written, in my opinion, and you don't seem to have a solid understanding of how hooks work yet. I'd suggest going through [this introduction](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) until you feel comfortable with what's going on.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll read the introduction.

Comment: I think there's something wrong inside `React.useEffect()`. If you wanna subscribe to the event when the components get mounted and unsubscribe when the components get unmounted then you should pass `[]` as dependency for the former and return the function that unsubscribe (from the function that you passed in `useEffect`) for the latter. You can find it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

Comment: @Lcj what editor do you use? If you use VS Code I suggest installing the [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) extension, and adding both [`eslint`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint) and [`eslint-plugin-react-hooks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) to your `package.json`. You'll need to follow the instructions on those last two links, but after it's set up, you'll get realtime warnings in your editor when you use hooks incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start of by why things are going wrong. The issue is that when you call `onNewItem(newItem)` you are using an outdated reference to the `onNewItem`. For this reason `items` within the function will still be set to the initial value.

You partially solved this by providing an dependency array to `React.useCallback`. This will update `onNewItem` when a new value of `items` is available. However since `React.useEffect` does not list `onNewItem` as a dependency it keeps using the old version of `onNewItem`.

With this being said you might consider adding `onNewItem`, to the dependency array of `React.useEffect`. Although this is the correct action, just adding this to dependency array is not enough.

What is the problem you get when you add `onNewItem` to the depency array of `React.useEffect`? There is no cleanup function, so you will subscribe to the channel multiple times with different `onmessage` handlers (different versions of `onNewItem`).

So taking all the above into account a solution might look something like this:

```
function TodoListCard() {
  const [items, setItems] = React.useState(null);
  const [events, setEvents] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const pEvents = fetch('/items')
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(setItems)
      .then(() => new EventSource('/events/subscribe'));

    pEvents.then(setEvents);

    return () => pEvents.then(events => events.close());
  }, []);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!events) return;
    events.onmessage = (event) => {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(event.data);
      switch (parsedData.type) {
        case "add":
          var newItem = {
            id: parsedData.id,
            name: parsedData.name,
            completed: parsedData.completed
          };
          onNewItem(newItem);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
    };
  }, [events, onNewItem]);

  const onNewItem = React.useCallback(newItem => {
    const isPresent = items.some(item => item.id === newItem.id);
    if (isPresent) return;
    setItems([...items, newItem]);
  }, [items]);

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

I've moved the `EventSource` creation inside the first `React.useEffect` since that only needs to happen once the component is mounted (and needs to close the connection on unmount). An empty dependency array will only call the function on mount, and calls the cleanup function on unmount.

The second `React.useEffect` now has the dependency array `[events, onNewItem]`, because when `events` is set the `onmessage` handler needs to be attached. And if the `onNewItem` callback updates to a new version you should attach it as the new `onmessage` handler (replacing the old handler). This doesn't need a cleanup function anymore since, opening and closing `events` is already handled.

Although the above should do the job. If managing a specific state is becoming more complicated it might be better to opt for [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) instead of `useState`.

```
function reducer(items, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "add":
      const isPresent = items.some(item => item.id == action.item.id);
      if (isPresent) return items;
      return [...items, action.item];

    case "replace all":
      return action.items;

    case "complete": // <- unused example case
      return items.map(item => {
        if (item.id != action.id) return item;
        return {...item, completed: true};
      });

    // ...

    default: // silently ignore unsupported operations
      return items;
  }
}

function TodoListCard() {
  const [items, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const pEvents = fetch('/items')
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(items => dispatch({type: "replace all", items}))
      .then(() => new EventSource('/events/subscribe'));

    pEvents.then(events => {
      events.onmessage = (event) => {
        const {type, ...item} = JSON.parse(event.data);
        dispatch({type, item});
      };
    });

    return () => pEvents.then(events => events.close());
  }, []);

  // if you still need onNewItem for your render:
  const onNewItem = React.useCallback(item => {
    dispatch({type: "add", item});
  }, []);

  return (
    // ...
  );
}
```

The above extracts all the `items` management logic into a "reducer" function. The `dispatch` function returned by `useReducer` is guaranteed to be stable by React, so you can omit it from dependency arrays (but you don't have to).

Answer (score -1):

The error that you have done is you are not getting any data from your api.The `setItems` in your first `useEffect`  won't work.

Wrong Way:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/items')
        .then(r => r.json())
        .then(setItems);
}, []);
```

Right Way:

```
useEffect(() => {
      fetch('/items')
          .then(r => r.json())
          .then((result) => {
            setItems(result.items)
          });
  }, []);
```

Comment: This is not the problem. The JSON returned by the server is the array itself. And `.then(result => setItems(result))` is equivalent to `.then(setItems)`.